# How to change Bootstrap Carousel slide time (not data-interval) with javascript

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, transition, slide

While using Bootstrap Carousel when you click next, the other item in the carousel gets active class after a time and that time is set by -css transition time left- by default. But i've disabled sliding left between items, so i need to set a time between slides with javascript without using any css transitions, i'm using css animations in the inner elements of the item. So i have to remove any animation,transition happening to .item.

Any help would be great !

Comment: I do not quite understand your question. Could you improve it or add some code you have tried? I'm sending a code I wrote in **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qelac/2/edit)**, which I removed the transition to element `.item` within the `.carousel-inner`. See if that helps you. **http://jsbin.com/qelac/2/edit**

Comment: Thanks for the jsbin, that is exactly what i've done but if you click next it instantly goes to second item, it needs to wait 1s, than go to next slide, is it possible to do it ?